# Как правильно сформулировать систему скидок?

Tags: php, yii

У меня есть массив вот я вывожу с модели:

```
$model = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()-> 
select( '*' )-> 
from('DiscountRegular')-> 
where('active = "1"')-> 
queryAll();
```

Данные такие:

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> 
array(7) { 
["id"]=> 
string(1) "1" 
["name"]=> 
string(6) "7roses" 
["active"]=> 
string(1) "1" 
["sum"]=> 
string(2) "10" 
["start_date"]=> 
string(19) "2018-10-25 13:40:07" 
["end_date"]=> 
string(19) "2018-11-30 09:45:28" 
["price"]=> 
string(3) "351" 
} 
[1]=> 
array(7) { 
["id"]=> 
string(1) "2" 
["name"]=> 
string(1) "2" 
["active"]=> 
string(1) "1" 
["sum"]=> 
string(2) "20" 
["start_date"]=> 
string(19) "2018-10-30 10:25:40" 
["end_date"]=> 
string(19) "2018-11-30 10:25:40" 
["price"]=> 
string(3) "250" 
} 
}
```

Как мне перебрать такой пример: если в покупателя общая сумма оплачена 250 или больше тогда ему % скидки будет 20% а если больше 351 или равно тогда 10%?

Условие я сделал такое:

```
if($result == $model[0]['price'] or $result > $model[0]['price']){
```

т.е мне надо как-то сделать что бы действовала скидка по значению ["price"], а у меня почему-то сейчас работает не правильно хоть и указана сумма покупок 351 скидка на 250 не работает.

Я это всё сделал так:

```
public function checkDiscount($price) 
{ 
$model = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()-> 
select( '*' )-> 
from('DiscountRegular')-> 
where('active = "1"')-> 
queryAll(); 

$regular_discount = DiscountRegular::calculateDiscount(); 
$result = preg_replace("/\..+/", "", $regular_discount); 

if($result == $model[0]['price'] or $result > $model[0]['price']){ 
$timestamp_start = strtotime($model[0]['start_date']); 
$timestamp_stop = strtotime($model[0]['end_date']); 


if($timestamp_start <= time() && $timestamp_stop >= time() && $model[0]['active'] == '1') 
{ 
$percent = $model[0]['sum']; 
$number_percent = $price / 100 * $percent; 
$result = $price - $number_percent; 

return $result; 

}else{ 
return false; 
} 
}else{ 
return false; 
} 
}
```

Вот без использования фреймворка пример

```
public function checkDiscount($price)
{
$model = 'SELECT *FROM `DiscountRegular` WHERE active = "1"';//отдаст запись (си) скидок на пример
/* array(2) {
[0]=>
array(7) {
["id"]=>
string(1) "1"
["name"]=>
string(6) "7roses"
["active"]=>
string(1) "1"
["sum"]=>
string(2) "10"
["start_date"]=>
string(19) "2018-10-25 13:40:07"
["end_date"]=>
string(19) "2018-11-30 09:45:28"
["price"]=>
string(3) "351"
}
 */
$regular_discount = '$351'; //это общая сумма покупок выведет на пример $351
$result = preg_replace("/\..+/", "", $regular_discount);//тут я убираю первый смвол

if($result == $model[0]['price'] or $result > $model[0]['price']){
$timestamp_start = strtotime($model[0]['start_date']);
$timestamp_stop = strtotime($model[0]['end_date']);


if($timestamp_start <= time() && $timestamp_stop >= time() && $model[0]['active'] == '1')
{
$percent = $model[0]['sum'];
$number_percent = $price / 100 * $percent;
$result = $price - $number_percent;

return $result;

}else{
return false;
}
}else{
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: `preg_replace('/\..+/', "", "$351")` ваше регулярка не срабатывает. знак `$` не удаляет. Соответственно условия уже работать будут не правильно

Comment: У меня работает

Comment: Допустим. В начале вы показываете массив с двумя скидками (для сумм 250 и более  351). Но согласно вашему условию, вы проверяете только первый элемент массива `$model[0]`